# How do you integrate a RadEditor control into a Sitefinity custom designer?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4, sitefinity-5

On Sitefinity 4.x or 5.x CMS, how do you add a RadEditor to a custom widget? I currently have a regular text field and it works fine, however I would like to provide more functionality to the edit text.

I have a working custom widget that includes a working custom designer. No problems, there, just wondering about the specifics in integrating the RadEditor.

Answer (score 2):

in Sitefinity the RadEditor is wrapped in an HtmlField which can be emedded in a control designer to allow rich text input.

Here's some info on creating control designers: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-09-20/creating_advanced_sitefinity_4_widget_control_designers.aspx

And a blog post that demonstrates a control designer using the HtmlField: http://www.avisra.com/blog/2011/05/22/sitefinity-control-designer-fields

hope this is helpful!